# Listview custom ListDivider

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm actually creating a ListView by populating items from the database.
When the end of the listview is reached I populate a few more items. Now, I want the dividers of the ListView based on the value returned from the database. If two consecutive values of the database are same I want them to be seperated by a thinline and if not a thick line.

I tried setting them through the adapter like this

```
if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            if (eventSource.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("asdsadas")
                    && eventSource.get(position + 1).equalsIgnoreCase(
                            "fdgdfgfd")
                    || eventSource.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase(
                            "dfgdfgdfg")
                    && eventSource.get(position + 1).equalsIgnoreCase(
                            "jgghjhhgg")) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_adapter, null);
            } else {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_adapterthinline,
                        null);
            }
```

I'm inflating a new layout based on the condition. It works for the first time, but after I scroll down and come up the view changes. It gets all mixed up.

I tried setting the divider height in the Activity too, like this and I call the 'setdivider' method in onCreate and in onScroll listener too.

```
public void setdivider() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < listSource.size() - 1; i++) {


            if (!listSource.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(
                    listSource.get(i + 1))) {
                Log.v("inside not equals", "become smalllllllllllllllll");
                list.setDivider(red);
                list.setDividerHeight(5);
            } else if (listSource.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(
                    listSource.get(i + 1))) {
                Log.v("inside equals", "become bigggggggggggg");
                list.setDivider(blue);
                list.setDividerHeight(10);
            }
        }
    }
```

But here even though both the log comments are shown on the LogCat, only one divider is set in the list.
Please tell me where I'm going wrong, or do suggest some other approaches, if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` caches views, so when you scroll around, view are reused. This is why `convertView` isn't always null. However, since you have two different kinds of views, you need to tell that to the `ListView` so that the `convertView` you get back is the kind you want. You do that by implementing `Adapter.getItemViewType()` and `Adapter.getViewTypeCount()`.

In your example, you would let `getViewTypeCount` return 2, and let `getItemViewType` return 1 if it's a divider, and 0 if it's not.

Comment: For anyone wondering how its done, go through this link http://logc.at/2011/10/10/handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types/

Answer (score 0):

merge the layout R.layout.list_adapter and R.layout.list_adapterthinline
with one single layout.

and set the thinline gone by default. and set it visible when you needs

..... Your layout here.

when you needs the line.

```
convertView.findViewById(R.id.thin_line).setVisible(View.Visible)
```

When you don't need it.

convertView.findViewById(R.id.thin_line).setVisible(View.Gone)

Comment: Thanks for answering;but this doesnt work. Its the same as what I did. It displays properly, but goes haywire after scrolling down and coming up. I guess the created views are reused and the dividers get mixed up.

Comment: I think you forgot to set the thinline Gone.

Comment: No. I didnt forget it. I did that too.